# React Router passing params. How to?

Tags: reactjs, parameters, react-router

Having the following React Router

```
const AppRoutes = (
  <Route path="/" handler={Properties}>
    <DefaultRoute handler={PropertyList} />
    <Route path="property/:propId" handler={PropertyDetail}/>
    <NotFoundRoute handler={NotFound} />
  </Route>);

Router.run(AppRoutes, Router.HashLocation, (Root) => {
  React.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('filter-content'));
});
```

I try to build dynamic links inside of a child Component and here I have a test

```
<Link to="/property/" params={{ propId: "123"}} ><img src={this.props.data.picture} 
                         data-srcset="http://placehold.it/350x150"  alt="" className="lazyload auto-height" 
                                 data-sizes="auto"/>
                    </Link>
```

but clicking on the link the propId is not getting passed,  what I do wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order for that to work you need to use the route name in the **to** property of **Link** component, otherwise router can't know which route definition you mean and therefore what to do with the **propId** parameter.

First, define a name for your route

```
<Route name="property" path="property/:propId" handler={PropertyDetail}/>
```

and then use the name when generating the link:

```
<Link to="/property/:propId" params={{ propId: "123"}} >
```

Comment: I believe named routes have been removed with 1.0+.

Comment: I get this with your suggest "Warning: Unknown prop `params` on <a> tag. Remove this prop from the element.