# Passing value between pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm not able to send data when user right clicks on the link and **selects Open link in new tab** but works perfectly fine when user does a left click on link.

```
<Link to={{pathname: '/student/edit',state:{userId:rowData.id}}}>
  Edit
</Link>
```

/student/edit is a path defined in my Routes

```
<Route exact path="/student/edit" component={StudentCandidate}/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass state to a new window/tab.  Instead, you would need to pass the data as parameters:

```
<Link to={{pathname: '/student/edit', userId: rowData.id}}>
  Edit
</Link>
```

Then in your Route, expect them in the `path`

```
<Route exact path="/student/edit/:userId" component={StudentCandidate}/>
```

Consider this similar SO question/answer: [React Router passing params. How to?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31771210/88732)

Comment: For some reason the above code did work, however thanks for letting me know that I cannot pass state to new tab. I used a search key inside "to" object and later retrieve the parameter.